# In C#, How do I monitor what goes in and out my ip sockets that other programs are using?

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp

Trying to make console app that monitors alongside its main program, and monitors what the main program has going in and what goes out its tcp/ip sockets. I have seen people do this in a few programs, but I can't figure out how. Something about using a raw socket, but I am not sure.

Any ideas how?

Answer (score 2):

If you want the console app to be entirely separate from the main program, you can do this various ways:

1. Create a man-in-the-middle proxy for the connections.  Run a client and server socket from your console application - i.e. clients connect to your proxy server and then your proxy server will forward the connection to your main program.  This allows you to record the packets on their way through your console.
2. Hook winsock.dll.  Essentially you will be gaining access to the parameters of send() and recv() calls that your main program makes, and you can then output or do as you like with it.
3. Forget programming it, and use Wireshark or another network sniffer to check what's going in or out.

---

More information on number 2:

It was surprisingly difficult to find good tutorials in C#, mainly because it's generally done with C++ or C.  Some links to get you started:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hooking

http://csns.calstatela.edu/download.html?fileId=2062150

http://www.elitepvpers.com/forum/co2-programming/1917917-c-dll-injecting-hooking.html

A tool to assist with hooking: http://easyhook.codeplex.com

I'll update this list as I find better resources.  I might make a tutorial myself, will keep you informed.

Comment: Number 3 for me. Unless it's a learning exercise, why reinvent what someone else has already done, and already done very well.

Comment: Sounds interesting, you got any tutorials you suggestion on that one for C#.

Comment: Winsock hooks are also effective at forcing other applications to connect to your proxy.... then the hook (which is a lot simpler when only `connect` needs to be overridden) can be C or C++, and the entire data processing performed in the C# proxy.

Comment: That's a good point Ben, doing it that way can minimise the C/C++ programming side.  For number 1 it's good practise to hook connect to get  the remote IP and force the main program to connect to the proxy.